# Extract content inside curly braces using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string

```
let str = 'foo ${bar}baz ${foobar}'
```

I want to extract all the elements between the `${` and `}`.
So I would want to return `['bar', 'foobar']`, ideally using `String`'s `match()` function in Javascript.  Any brilliant regex wizards out there willing to lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this if a Regex is not a real constraint :

```
let str = 'foo ${bar}baz ${foobar}'

console.log(str.split("${").slice(1).map(item => item.split("}")[0]))
// Outputs : ["bar", "foobar"]
```

Otherwise, here is a Regex that might fit your need : `\${(.*?)}`.

Comment: Thanks, was overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'foo ${bar}baz ${foobar}',
    exp = /\$\{(\w*)\}/g,
    matched,
    matches = [];

while ((matched = exp.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(matched[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
// Outputs: ["bar", "foobar"]
```

Comment: While this might possibly be the correct answer, it doesn't look convincing without commentaries and only code. Please consider adding a commentary for a better chance of being accepted.